# AWS Alexa skill linking with oauth 2

Tags: php, oauth-2.0, alexa-skills-kit

**Hello to all**

I am new in Amazon Alexa, I have a work to Alexa Skill account linking using PHP with oauth 2.0.

I have successfully configured all and also get code for `Auth Code Grant` but when I run my code in Chrome Browser it is generating `Account linking Failed` issue but when I run same URL in Firefox it generates `Amazon linking failed` with `ERROR=missing-state`.

Please help me to resolve my issue, any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Implementing `Account Linking` is tricky at times. The thing is at some point what happens between Alexa and the OAuth2 server is transparent for the Skill (Lambda), for example the process of refreshing a token among others, that is why I suggest you take a look at the references cited below.

Also because of the error shown, it seems that the parameter `code` is missing in one of the URLs exchanged back and forth between either the Alexa web console or Alexa mobile app and the OAuth2 server. Please verify it is always the same and is always present in the URLs. Implementing a proxy for sure will help on debugging this issue.

I would suggest you take a look at these great sources:

- [Debugging Account Linking](https://forums.developer.amazon.com/articles/38610/alexa-debugging-account-linking.html)
- [Using API Gateway to Debug Account Linking issues](https://developer.amazon.com/blogs/post/TxQN2C04S97C0J/How-to-Set-up-Amazon-API-Gateway-as-a-Proxy-to-Debug-Account-Linking)

I hope this helps somehow. 
Cheers

Comment: thanks for your answer but i am using php to create oauth2 server for authentication and i have also debug that Code param is always there with redirect url and state is also there, but after redirect i got "Linking failed and also getting `missing-state` in url" even i have checked there is state with redirect url with code...